# Не отображается капча на телефоне. 1-ый скрин с телфона, 2-ой с пк в режиме отображения на смартфоне

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[![1[image: ][1][1]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем может быть связана проблема не отображения изображения капчи?1-ый скрин с телфона, 2-ой с пк в режиме отображения на смартфоне.

Comment: для создания капчи использовал veriword.php

Comment: это примерно как диагноз ставить по фотографии,а не данным анализа и обследований.